# Convexity of (Probability) Simplex - Understanding the question

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, simplex

Take the $n-1$-simplex, $\Delta$, whose vertices are the $n$ standard unit vectors and let $\mu \in$ int $\Delta$. Define a probability distribution with finite support and barycenter $\mu, P_k$, to be a collection of points $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ (this is the support of $P_k$, i.e., $\operatorname{supp} P_k=\left\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\right\}$ ) with $x_i \in \Delta$ for all $i=1, \ldots, k$, and probabilities $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ with $p_i \in[0,1]$ for all $i=1, \ldots, k, \sum_{i=1}^k p_i=1$, and $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i x_i=\mu$. That is,

$P_k\equiv\{(x_1, \ldots, x_k, p_1, \ldots, p_k): x_i \in \Delta, p_i \in[0,1] \forall i, \sum_{i=1}^k p_i=1, \sum_{i=1}^k p_i x_i=\mu\}$

Define $\mathcal{P}:=\{P_k: k \in \mathbb{N}\}$

**The question asks to show that $\mathcal{P}$ convex.**

What I understand is the following:

1- Each $P_k$ is a probability simplex.

2- $\mathcal{P}$ has (possibly) many elements for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that is for $k=2$ there are different $P_k$s and same goes for $k > 3$.

3- Since the coordinates do not match for different $k$s, the convex combinations are only possible for fixed $k$.

**4- Taking $x^{\lambda}$ and $p^{\lambda}$ to be convex combinations of partial elements of any $P_k', P_k''$ with the associated $\lambda \in (0,1)$, is the convex combination element $P_k^{\lambda} \overset{?}{=} (x^{\lambda}, p^{\lambda})$? If not, if you can let me know which elements to combine and the reason, that would be sufficient.**

Thank you!

Comment: That first paragraph is hard to understand with all the interrupting parentheses and $\equiv$, and $\Delta$ is not defined.

Comment: I think the set $\mathcal{P}$ is intended to be $\mathcal{P}=\times_{i=1}^{\infty} P_k$ (for which convexity is relevant). It is currently written as $\mathcal{P}=\{P_k:k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which is just a list of sets in different dimensional spaces, for which convexity would not be relevant.

Comment: @Michael The First paragraph has now changed to the original wording. Thanks for your comment. Is it more clear now for any further light on the matter?

Comment: The first paragraph is more understandable, but the issue  $\mathcal{P}=\times_{k=1}^{\infty} P_k$ or $\mathcal{P}=\{P_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ remains. If $\mathcal{P}=\{P_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ then $\mathcal{P}$ is a countably infinite list of sets, so its cardinality is the same as $\mathbb{N}$, and there are no convex sets with such cardinality. For example if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two sets in different vector spaces $V_1, V_2$, then $P_1 \times P_2$ and $\{P_1, P_2\}$ are different, and $|\{P_1, P_2\}|=2$ but $|P_1\times P_2|$ can be infinite.

Comment: The $n-1$ simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an empty interior, so you lost me in the first sentence.

Comment: @copper.hat the definition I have for n-simplex is as followed:

- An $n$-simplex $T=x^0 \cdots x^n$ is the convex hull of an $n+1$ element affinely independent set. Each $x^i$ is a vertex of $T$ and each $k$-simplex $x^{i_0} \cdots x^{i_k}$ is a face of $T$.

- The standard $n$-simplex is the set $\Delta_n=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_i \geq 0\right.$ for $i=0, \ldots, n$ and $\left.\sum_{i=0}^n x_i=1\right\}$.

Comment: @Michael I also have the same issue understanding the question. Disregarding that issue with fixing $k$ and checking convexity in each fixed k $P_k$s, do you have suggestions how should I proceed with the rest?

Comment: Hence the $n-1$ simplex is contained in a $n-1$ dimensional affine space and so has empty interior.

Comment: @Pluviaum  : The question is not posed correctly, likely it was a typo at the source. Likely you are expected to show something similar to: If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two convex sets in vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, respectively, then show $P_1 \times P_2$ is convex.